# How to expand_dims an unknown number of times in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

If the number of dimensions of an element is known then I can call `tf.expand_dims`. How do I put `tf.expand_dims` in a loop? The following code works in eager but not in graph mode.

```py
# @tf.function
def broadcast_multiply(x, y):
    print(tf.shape(x)) # [2, 2, ?, ?, ... ?]
    print(tf.shape(y)) # [2, 2]

    # Doesnt work in graph mode but works in eager
    rank_diff = tf.rank(x) - tf.rank(y)
    for _ in tf.range(rank_diff):
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, -1)

    return x * y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [`tf.broadcast_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to)

```
def broadcast_multiply(x, y):
    y = tf.broadcast_to(y, tf.shape(x))
    return x * y
```

Answer (score 1):

After much headbanging this is what I came up with. Not the most performant, but it does the job. I wish tensorflow had inbuilt support for this. Numpy already does.

```py
@tf.function
def match_shapes(x, y):
    # Find which one needs to be broadcasted
    low, high = (y, x) if tf.rank(x) > tf.rank(y) else (x, y)
    l_rank, l_shape = tf.rank(low), tf.shape(low)
    h_rank, h_shape = tf.rank(high), tf.shape(high)
    
    # Find the difference in ranks
    common_shape = h_shape[:l_rank]
    tf.debugging.assert_equal(common_shape, l_shape, 'No common shape to broadcast')
    padding = tf.ones(h_rank - l_rank, dtype=tf.int32)
    
    # Pad the difference with ones and reshape
    new_shape = tf.concat((common_shape, padding),axis=0)
    low = tf.reshape(low, new_shape)

    return high, low

@tf.function
def broadcast_multiply(x, y):
    x, y = match_shapes(x, y)
    return x * y
    
x = tf.ones((3, 3, 2)) * 3
y = tf.ones((3, 3)) * 2
broadcast_multiply(x, y)
```

Result

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the following solution worked for me:

```
rank_diff = tf.rank(x) - tf.rank(y)
y = y[(...,) + rank_diff * (tf.newaxis,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use reshape:

```
tf.reshape(y, shape=tf.concat([tf.shape(y),  tf.ones(tf.rank(x) - 2)], 0))
```